# How to split key/value pairs in an array?

Tags: c#, json

I have this type of key value is stored in my database:

```
[{"SelFoodId":"2","SelQuantity":"5"},
 {"SelFoodId":"7","SelQuantity":"3"},
 {"SelFoodId":"9","SelQuantity":"7"}]
```

But now I want to split this JSON array in this form in c# like

```
SelFoodId = {2,7}, SelQuantity  = {5,7}
```

Comment: and what is it that you've tried?

Comment: 1. Deserialize the JSON. 2. Create the two lists in some kind of loop. 3. ??? 4. Profit

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear at the moment - partly because you've got 6 values in your input and 4 values in your expected output. I would strongly recommend using Json.NET to parse to a `List<Foo>` where `Foo` has `SelFoodId` and `SelQuantity` properties, and then work from there.

Comment: @john, +1 for the profit, it made my day

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Go here ([json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)) and create some objects out of your *JSON*

Which will give you something like this

```
public class MyAwesomeSomething
{
    public string SelFoodId { get; set; }
    public string SelQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

**2.** Add the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) *Nuget* package [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

**3.** Look up [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Method (String)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) and this [helpful sample](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm)

> Deserializes the JSON to a .NET object.n.

**4.** Write some code

**Exmaple**

```
var json = "[{\"SelFoodId\":\"2\",\"SelQuantity\":\"5\"},{\"SelFoodId\":\"7\",\"SelQuantity\":\"3\"},{\"SelFoodId\":\"9\",\"SelQuantity\":\"7\"}]";
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyAwesomeSomething>>(json);    
foreach(var item in list)       
{   
    Console.WriteLine(item.SelFoodId + " " + item.SelQuantity);
}
```

**Output**

```
2 5
7 3
9 7
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/px0oRE)